# Differential Equations: Guarantee Unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is the question that I'm working on:

> Let's consider the following first order differential equation $$(t^2-\pi^2)y' + (t-1)y = \sin(2t)$$
>
> For what specific initial conditions, call it $(t_0,y_0)$, can we guarantee a **unique solution**?

My approach would be to solve this equation for $y'$ (or $\frac{dy}{dt}$). Having said that, we have the following:

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y,t) = \frac {\sin(2t)-(t-1)y}{t^2-\pi^2}$$

Before taking the partial derivative of this expression with respect to $t$, I noticed that there is a domain issue already for $\frac{dy}{dt}$: $t \neq\pi$ since we will yield $0$ in the denominator. Then, I take the partial derivative and get

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{(t^2-\pi^2)[2\cos(2t)-y] - 2t\sin(2t)+2yt(t-1)}{(t^2-\pi^2)^2}$$

The algebra doesn't look so bad (I haven't dealt with partial fractions that much), but the partial derivative isn't continuous when $t = \pi$. So does this mean that we cannot guarantee a unique solution. Any insight on this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: A unique solution for what time interval?

Comment: There are two singularities at $t=\pm \pi$, so you'll get a solution in one of 3 intervals $(-\infty,-\pi)$, $(-\pi,\pi)$, $(\pi,\infty)$ depending on where the initial condition is

Comment: I'm not given a specific time interval Paul.

Comment: I think it has unique solution when $t_0 \ne \pm \pi$ and $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hmmm do I just have to guess what my initial condition is in order to get a solution? If so, how can I make an constructed educated guess such that I get the correct solution within the 3 time intervals?

Comment: Alex Vong. Yeah I definitely agree with $t_0$ not being $\pm \pi$, but since there is no domain issue when $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, is this a sufficient condition to show that such a unique solution exists?

Comment: @JohnSmith You may want to read [Theorem 2.2](http://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk./course_builder/1718/math3270a/MA3270a_Chap2.pdf), it says a first order linear IVP with continuous coefficients on an open interval has a unique solution.

Comment: @Alex Wong Sounds good. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Again, it depends on where the given point is. For example if the I.C. is $y(0)=y_0$ then you have a solution on $(-\pi,\pi)$. For every I.C. you can get a solution in **one** of these intervals

Comment: You are absolutely right, if we are given $(0, y_0)$ as the IC, then $(-\pi, \pi)$ is the largest interval containing $0$ where the coefficients are still continuous. The unique solution should only be defined on $(-\pi, \pi)$ by the theorem. But I think the important part is that, given IC $t_0 \ne \pi, y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, the solution is still unique in the largest interval containing $t_0$ where the coefficients are still continuous. I think this should be good enough for the OP, or not?

Comment: Hi Alex. Yes it is now very clear to me.